# How to split pandas dataframe into multiple parts based on consecutively occuring values in a column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which I am representing in a tabular format below. The original dataframe is a lot bigger in size and therefore I cannot afford to loop on each row.

```
col1 | col2 | col3
a      x     1
b      y     1
c      z     0
d      k     1
e      l     1
```

What I want is split it into subsets of dataframes with consecutive number of `1`s in the column `col3`.
So ideally I want to above dataframe to return two dataframes `df1` and `df2`

`df1`

```
col1 | col2 | col3
a      x     1
b      y     1
```

`df2`

```
col1 | col2 | col3
d      k     1
e      l     1
```

Is there an approach like `groupby` to do this? 
If I use `groupby` it returns me all the 4 rows in a dataframe with `col3==1`. 
I do not want that as I need two dataframes each consisting of consecutively occuring `1`s.
One method is to obviously loop by the rows and as and when I find a 0, I can return a dataframe but that is not efficient. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

First compare values by `1`, then create consecutive groups by `shift` and cumulative sum and last in list comprehension with `groupby` get all groups:

```
m1 = df['col3'].eq(1)
g = m1.ne(m1.shift()).cumsum()

dfs = [x for i, x in df[m1].groupby(g)]
print (dfs)
[  col1 col2  col3
0    a    x     1
1    b    y     1,   col1 col2  col3
3    d    k     1
4    e    l     1]

print (dfs[0])
  col1 col2  col3
0    a    x     1
1    b    y     1
```

If also is necessary remove single `1` rows is added [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `keep=False`:

```
print (df)
  col1 col2  col3
0    a    x     1
1    b    y     1
2    c    z     0
3    d    k     1
4    e    l     1
5    f    m     0
6    g    n     1 <- removed

m1 = df['col3'].eq(1)
g = m1.ne(m1.shift()).cumsum()

g = g[g.duplicated(keep=False)]
print (g)
0    1
1    1
3    3
4    3
Name: col3, dtype: int32

dfs = [x for i, x in df[m1].groupby(g)]
print (dfs)
[  col1 col2  col3
0    a    x     1
1    b    y     1,   col1 col2  col3
3    d    k     1
4    e    l     1]
```